# initialize empty EditText in ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I have `ListView` and it include 2 `EditText`I want to initialize 6 empty `EditText` when activity started.How can I do that?

I can not add list null Model and set it  so I dont know how can i handle it.

> This is listview_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/SerialNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/countItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="number">
</EditText>
```

This is my layout;

> activity_reader.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content""
    android:text="btn" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />
</GridLayout>
```

Here is the ListView Adapter;

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<Model> productList;
Activity activity;
ViewHolder holder;
public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Census> productList) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.productList = productList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return productList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    EditText SerialNumber;
    EditText countItem;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.SerialNumber = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SerialNumber );
        holder.countItem = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countItem );;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.SerialNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        holder.SerialNumber.requestFocus();

    }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            holder.censusRowSerialNumber.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //holder.countItem.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    Model item = productList.get(position);
    holder.SerialNumber.setText(item.getID().toString());
    holder.countItem.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

> Here is the Activity;

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText countItem,SerialNumber;
private ArrayList<Model> csList;
Model item;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ListView lview;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);

    csList = new ArrayList<Model>();
    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, csList);

    SerialNumber= findViewById(R.id.SerialNumber);
    countItem = findViewById(R.id.countItem );
    lview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

Comment: I could not understand why to use ListView inside GridLayout?  What I understood and you could do is  Create a custom LinearLayout. Add edittext's to the view using LayoutInflator. Iterate according the number of rows you needed. Add it to the rootlayout

Comment: My ListView is inside GridLayout because of design other things include activity but i dont write them. Can GridLayout effect my listview?I want to do actually dynamically listview when added Model to list view is increase but i want set the beggining 5-6 editText in my ListView

Comment: First of all, rather than listview , you can use RecyclerView .Example https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/  Now, if you use these kind of layouts, dynamic CRUD operation will be difficult. So rather than that go with approach which I told you (Custom layout). I will put up an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieving `CRUD` operations, its good to go with Custom Layouts.

For instance a `LinearLayout`, who's default layout is already defined. Now according to runtime requirement/parameters you can add/edit/delete all these. For which the logic can be completely yours. This is handy than creating a static view and manipulating.

Let me show you custom layouts preparation and adding into a rootiew. I have given example where layout `landing_hori_view` is having an `EditText` and `Button`

```
public class LandingHorizontalView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener{


public LandingHorizontalView(Context context){
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }
public LandingHorizontalView(Context context, ModelClassObject modelObject,ButtonClicked listener){
        super(context);
        mTypeContent = modelObject;//If you want to pass some params for population
        mListener = listener;
        initialize();
    }
private void initialize(){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.landing_hori_view, this, true);
        EditText edtOne =findViewById(R.id.txt_price_list);
        Button button= findViewById(R.id.btn_place_order);
        button.setTag(count);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v instanceof  Button){
            int count = (int) v.getTag();
            mListener.onButtonClicked(count);
        }

    }

public interface ButtonClicked{
        public void onButtonClicked(int index);
    }
}
```

In your parent activity, implement the interface (here `ButtonClicked`) and handle click events/manipulating UI etc

```
@Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int index) {

}
```

Now coming to , how to add these to parent layout, create a `ScrollView` and include one `LinearLayout` to which `LandinghorizontalView` will be added.

Below shows content of my parent Activity

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/landingScrollLinearView"
            >

        </LinearLayout>
```

Now for adding this vew , the following can be done.

```
    LandingHorizontalView horizontalView=new LandingHorizontalView(getActivity(),modelObject,this);
    mScrollLinearView.addView(horizontalView);
```

> Now as per your comment, create few `LandingHorizontalView`  and add
>   to root. Now according to your logic/user interaction , keep on
>   modifying `mScrollLinearView`